# select link to add class select

Tags: jquery, addclass

Well, i have a problem to add a class name selected this is my html code:

```
<div class="module">
    <ul class="accordion">
        <li><a class="element" href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="element" href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a class="element" href="#areas" >Areas</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="heading" id="about">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="heading" id="services">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="heading" id="areas">
        ...
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both; display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

my CSS code

```
ul.accordion-btn li{list-style:none;float:left;padding:5px 10px;margin:0 1px 0;text-transform:uppercase;box-shadow:0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
ul.accordion-btn li{background:#fafaf9;}
.module h1{font-size:1.8em; font-weight:normal;}
.module{padding:0;margin:10px 0;}
ul.accordion-btn{display:table;}
ul.accordion-btn a{color:#1E587F;margin:0;}
.heading{display:block;float:left;width:660px;min-height:320px;}
.selected{color:#FFF;text-decoration:none;border-color:#1E587F;background-color: Yellow;}
```

so i'm using some jquery, need some help please

```
var tabContainers = $('div.module > div');
jQuery('.accordion').addClass('accordion-btn');
$('div.module ul.accordion a').click(function(){
    tabContainers.hide().filter(this.hash).fadeIn('fast');
    tabContainers.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
}).filter(':first').click();
```

Comment: what do you mean by .filter(this.has) ? I mean what you want to select? I think removing that will work for you.

Comment: @C-link OP is using `this.hash` which returns the hash part (_fragment identifier_) of the `href` property, a property of [`HTMLAnchorElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement) object. http://jsfiddle.net/s97Ps/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
var tabContainers = $('div.heading');
jQuery('.accordion').addClass('accordion-btn');
$('div.module ul.accordion a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    tabContainers.removeClass('selected').hide();
    $(this.hash).fadeIn('fast')
                .addClass('selected');
}).filter(':first').click();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yyg8Q/)

If you want to `add class` on `anchor` then try this,

```
$('div.module ul.accordion a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    tabContainers.removeClass('selected').hide();
    $(this.hash).fadeIn('fast');
    $(' ul.accordion a').removeClass('selected');// remove class from all active anchor
    $(this).addClass('selected');// make it selected/active
}).filter(':first').click();
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yyg8Q/1/)

Comment: but @RohanKumar in the same html file cause is a tab style, but thanks,

Comment: Excellent @RohanKumar so like i said the class is for the li>a.element

Comment: Well done so my problem was a 3 lines i thought the whole code, thanks @RohanKumar and Arun P Johny

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are targeting the div to add the class - because you are removing the class from the `tabContainers`

```
var tabContainers = $('div.module > div');
jQuery('.accordion').addClass('accordion-btn');
$('div.module ul.accordion a').click(function () {
    tabContainers.hide().removeClass('selected');
    $(this.hash).fadeIn('fast').addClass('selected');
}).filter(':first').click();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tcTge/)

Comment: hey @Arun P Johny the background is for the class element too i mean for this         <ul class="accordion">
        <li><a class="element" href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="element" href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a class="element" href="#areas" >Areas</a></li>
        </ul>

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){<br>
var tabContainers = $('div.module > div');<br>
jQuery('.accordion').addClass('accordion-btn');<br>
$('div.module ul.accordion a').click(function () {<br>
    $('div.module ul.accordion a').removeClass('selected');<br>
    tabContainers.hide();<br>
    $(this).addClass('selected');<br>
    $(this.hash).fadeIn('fast').addClass('selected');<br>
}).filter(':first').click();<br>
})
```